# How to reverse numeric value having scientific notation in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to understand best way to reverse an integer (both positive and negative) in NodeJS 12. Can we do this without converting number to string? It should also support **scientific notation** numbers like 1e+10 which is 10000000000.

```
Input/Expected Output
 
500 = 5
-94 = -49
1234 = 4321
-1 = -1
1e+10 = 1
123.45e+10 = 54321
```

Comment: strings are easily reversed - what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this way as optimized way I could come up with

parseInt(Math.sign(num) * parseInt(Math.abs(num).toString().split("").reverse().join("")))

Comment: so, did that work? seems it should - wouldn't need the parseInt's though

Comment: Please [search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+digits+using+math+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one line function solves your use-case

```js
// The Math.sign() function returns either a positive or negative +/- 1, 
// indicating the sign of a number passed into the argument.   

function reverseInt(n) {
  return parseInt(n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) * Math.sign(n)
}

console.log(reverseInt(500));
console.log(reverseInt(-94));
console.log(reverseInt(1234));
```

Comment: why would you need parseInt? seems a wasted function call

Comment: It ensures that it provides a valid result even if the passed argument is a stringified integer. I know this is not the usecase but still having it error resistant is a better approach

Comment: @Bravo: without parseInt, `-94` wouldn't  work.

Comment: @Bravo: reversing "-94" gives "49-" and calling `Number` on it directly would result in a `NaN`, therefore they need `parseInt` there. Surely, there are other ways to write the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I could come up with but I feel there might be better way. I didn't like the way I had to convert the integer to string, reverse it and again convert it back to integer.

```
parseInt(Math.sign(num) * parseInt(Math.abs(num).toString().split("").reverse().join("")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseNum(num) {
    return (
    parseFloat(
      num
        .toString()
        .split('')
        .reverse()
        .join('')
    ) * Math.sign(num)
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good but can we do it without converting to string?

Comment: Btw this will fail for such numbers having e+. Try this reverseNum(Number.MAX_VALUE)

Comment: if  string reverse negative number  it get  nan(not a number)  eg: -4545 => get 4545- * math.sign(num)

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the link. Always happy to have a TIL moment :)

Comment: Me too it was op’s “can we do it with out string that prompted me to look